# Spring Boot circular dependency conflict between Spring Boot Security, JPA, WebMVC and Cache

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jwt, circular-dependency

Building a web spring boot application with a JPA database connection. Working fine so far.
Now when implementing Spring Boot Security with a company internal library that enriches the original spring security dependency, I started facing a circular dependency issue.

Console:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle:

   servletEndpointRegistrar defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/endpoint/web/ServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration$WebMvcServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration.class]
      ↓
   cachesEndpoint defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/cache/CachesEndpointAutoConfiguration.class]
┌─────┐
|  cacheManager defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/cache/CaffeineCacheConfiguration.class]
↑     ↓
|  cacheManagerCustomizers defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/cache/CacheAutoConfiguration.class]
↑     ↓
|  jwtAppSecurityConfigurer (field private org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager internal.company.library.package.AbstractPreAuthSecurityConfigurer.authenticationManager)
↑     ↓
|  securityConfig (This is my SecurityConfig Class posted below)
↑     ↓
|  org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration
↑     ↓
|  openEntityManagerInViewInterceptorConfigurer defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration.class]
↑     ↓
|  openEntityManagerInViewInterceptor defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration.class]
└─────┘
```

SecurityConfig Class:

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    // This bean is created by internal spring authentication library
    @Autowired
    private JwtAppSecurityConfigurer jwtAppSecurityConfigurer;

    // Authorize everyone and everything for the moment
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/*").permitAll();
        // Apply jwtAppSecurityConfigurer
        jwtAppSecurityConfigurer.configure(httpSecurity);
    }

    // Exposing AuthenticationManager needed by internal library
    @Bean(name = BeanIds.AUTHENTICATION_MANAGER)
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
}
```

What I tried so far:

- The Team in the company that provides the library could not so far, but I don't think it is an issue with the library they provide. Rather me having something configured / used wrong.
- annotating methods, classes or the whole project to use @Lazy did NOT work
- removing everything related to JPA aswell as the dependency and the Project compiled again (but bringing other issues obviously)
- setting application.properties `#spring.cache.type=NONE` also made the project compile again (but bringing other issues obviously)

Anyone an idea what I can do to break the circular dependencies between the mentioned beans in the console?

**EDIT 1:**

application.properties (only JAP / database relevant configurations shown):

```
# ===============================
# = DATA SOURCE
# ===============================
# HikariCP settings
spring.datasource.hikari.connection-timeout=60000
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=5

# database connection config
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
spring.datasource.url= XXXXXXXXXX
# User and PW currently hard coded
spring.datasource.username= XXXXXXXXXX
spring.datasource.password= XXXXXXXXX

# Keep db connection alive
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle=true
spring.datasource.validationQuery=SELECT 1

# logging
logging.pattern.console=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=debug
org.springframework.beans.factory=ALL

# ===============================
# = JPA / HIBERNATE
# ===============================
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=false
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none

#Naming Strategy
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.implicit-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyLegacyHbmImpl
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
# spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
```

Comment: What Spring beans get autowired in `internal.company.library.package.AbstractPreAuthSecurityConfigurer.authenticationManager` field of `jwtAppSecurityConfigurer`?

Comment: In AbstractPreAuthSecurityConfigurer the bean of authenticationManager gets autowired. In jwtAppSecurityConfigurer nothing gets autowired.

Comment: Is `AbstractPreAuthSecurityConfigurer` used in the `jwtAppSecurityConfigurer` because it seems so? What are your Spring properties, particularly JPA?

Comment: Well JwtAppSecurityConfigurer extends AbstractPreAuthSecurityConfigurer. I'll add the application.properties related to JPA to the Question itself.

Comment: @FlavioCaduff  Did you find any solution?

Comment: @PrasanthRajendran Unfortunately not, sorry. I'm not working on that project anymore.